# C# and Selenium scraping dynamic loading website

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to develop an app for a Uni project. The app scrapes a sport betting website and gives me all the leagues and matches that will occur that day (football, tennis, basketball and handball).
I am using Selenium to navigate and scroll through the website. This takes more time and resources that I will to. Recently I found headless chrome and someone told me that it will reduce the time significantly. My problem is that I do not know when the page is fully loadead when using headless chrome. (On the old version I was waiting for the website to finish scraping all it s data).

I use this function to load the pages:

```
private static List<string> ScrapeLeagues(string url)
        {
            List<string> leagues = new List<string>();
            Dictionary<string, double> pozitii = new Dictionary<string, double>();
            HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
            IWebElement parent;
            IReadOnlyList<IWebElement> meciuri = new List<IWebElement>();
            string echipa1, echipa2;
            var timeout = 10000;
            var wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeout));
            webDriver.Url = url;
            wait.Until(d => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)d).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));
            var pageSource = webDriver.PageSource;
            htmlDoc.LoadHtml(pageSource);
            IReadOnlyList<IWebElement> divs = webDriver.FindElements(By.ClassName("group-header__details-title"));
            foreach (IWebElement div in divs)
            {
                leagues.Add(div.GetAttribute("title"));
                parent = (IWebElement)((IJavaScriptExecutor)webDriver).ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;", div);
                meciuri = parent.FindElements(By.ClassName("event-row-container"));
                _evenimente.Add(new Eveniment(div.GetAttribute("title"),meciuri.Count));
                foreach(IWebElement meci in meciuri)
                {
                    echipa1 = meci.FindElement(By.ClassName("event-summary__competitors-team1")).GetAttribute("title");
                    echipa2 = meci.FindElement(By.ClassName("event-summary__competitors-team2")).GetAttribute("title");
                    var cote = meci.FindElements(By.ClassName("e2e-odd-current-value"));
                    if (cote.Count == 3)
                    {
                        _evenimente.ElementAt(_evenimente.Count - 1).AdaugaMeci(echipa1, echipa2, cote[0].GetAttribute("innerHTML"), cote[1].GetAttribute("innerHTML"), cote[2].GetAttribute("innerHTML"));
                    }else if(cote.Count == 2)
                    {
                        _evenimente.ElementAt(_evenimente.Count - 1).AdaugaMeci(echipa1, echipa2, cote[0].GetAttribute("innerHTML"), cote[1].GetAttribute("innerHTML"));
                    }
                }
                pozitii.Add(div.GetAttribute("title"), Convert.ToDouble(div.Location.Y));
            }
            Int64 last_height = (Int64)(((IJavaScriptExecutor)webDriver).ExecuteScript("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight"));
            while (true)
            {
                ((IJavaScriptExecutor)webDriver).ExecuteScript("const element = document.getElementsByClassName('event-row-container');element[element.length-1].scrollIntoView(false);");
                //Thread.Sleep(15);
                pageSource = webDriver.PageSource;
                htmlDoc.LoadHtml(pageSource);
                divs = webDriver.FindElements(By.ClassName("group-header__details-title"));
                foreach (IWebElement div in divs)
                {
                    if (!pozitii.ContainsKey(div.GetAttribute("title")))
                    {
                        leagues.Add(div.GetAttribute("title"));
                        parent = (IWebElement)((IJavaScriptExecutor)webDriver).ExecuteScript("console.log(arguments[0].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode);return arguments[0].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;", div);
                        meciuri = parent.FindElements(By.ClassName("event-row-container"));
                        _evenimente.Add(new Eveniment(div.GetAttribute("title"), meciuri.Count));
                        foreach (IWebElement meci in meciuri)
                        {
                            echipa1 = meci.FindElement(By.ClassName("event-summary__competitors-team1")).GetAttribute("title");
                            echipa2 = meci.FindElement(By.ClassName("event-summary__competitors-team2")).GetAttribute("title");
                            var cote = meci.FindElements(By.ClassName("e2e-odd-current-value"));
                            if (cote.Count == 3)
                            {
                                _evenimente.ElementAt(_evenimente.Count - 1).AdaugaMeci(echipa1, echipa2, cote[0].GetAttribute("innerHTML"), cote[1].GetAttribute("innerHTML"), cote[2].GetAttribute("innerHTML"));
                            }
                            else if (cote.Count == 2)
                            {
                                _evenimente.ElementAt(_evenimente.Count - 1).AdaugaMeci(echipa1, echipa2, cote[0].GetAttribute("innerHTML"), cote[1].GetAttribute("innerHTML"));
                            }
                        }
                        pozitii.Add(div.GetAttribute("title"), Convert.ToDouble(div.Location.Y));
                    }
                }
                double new_height = Convert.ToDouble(((IJavaScriptExecutor)webDriver).ExecuteScript("return window.pageYOffset"));
                if (new_height + 2500 >= last_height)
                    break;
            }
            return leagues;
        }
```

I want to implement something like a loading screen untill the app finishes scraping the website. Can you give me any further hints ?
In main form I have following code:

```
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webProcessor = await WebsiteProcessor.getInstance();
            evenimente = WebsiteProcessor._evenimente;
        }
```

Comment: Selenium is not suitable for scraping scenarios, if you want to use browser-base bot try Playwright instead.

Comment: @ggeorge: how is selenium not suitable for scraping scenarios? Plenty of people use it. Furthermore, websites that load data dynamically still present challenges in Playwright, even if Playwright waits for elements by default. A dynamic site still requires the programmer to know which elements to wait for, and generally what user interaction triggers new data to be loaded.

Comment: Can you clarify the problem you are trying to solve? When running in headless mode, are you getting an exception? If so, please [edit] your question to include the message and full stack trace.

Comment: When running in headless mode, I do not know when the program finishes to scrape all pages of the website. I want to know this to limit the user interactions untill the scrape is finished.